# update listbox in GUI from other classes

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a listbox on my main vb.net form which I am using to display status messages from the server program I am running. My actual program consists of many different classes (in separate files) and what I would like to be able to do is to call the Sub frm.UpdateList("With Info in Here") from each of the classes to write to the listbox.

If I call the frm.UpdateList or UpdateList from the frm class, it writes to the listbox fine, but if I call it from any other class nothing happens (I don't get an error either).

I have tried with and without making it shared (and changing frm to me) but neither works as I would hope.

Would anyone be able to help me understand why this is not working, I have invoked the item, and it does get added to but just not from a separate class (which is what I need it to do).

Many Thanks!

```
Private Delegate Sub UpdateListDelegate(ByVal itemName As String)
    Public Shared Sub UpdateList(ByVal itemName As String)
        If frm.InvokeRequired Then
            frm.Invoke(New UpdateListDelegate(AddressOf UpdateList), itemName)
        Else
                            frm.ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString & ": " & itemName)
        End If
End Sub
```

Edit: Try 2, with the following thanks to Idle_Mind works on the frm class (frm is the main form and only form) but it still does not write to the listbox when called from other classes (and no errors occur):

```
Public Shared Sub UpdateList(ByVal itemName As String)
    Dim frm As Form = My.Application.ApplicationContext.MainForm
    If Not IsNothing(frm) Then
        Dim matches() As Control = frm.Controls.Find("ListBox1", True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is ListBox Then
            Dim LB As ListBox = DirectCast(matches(0), ListBox)
            LB.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() LB.Items.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString & ": " & itemName)))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is frm is the Form Object or the Class (Form) name ?

Comment: Why not simply provide a public method on the form which any actor can call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a listbox on my main vb.net form

This will only work on the startup form, and is not really a good design.  Consider other approaches as well:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim soc As New SomeOtherClass
        soc.Foo()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class SomeOtherClass

    Public Sub Foo()
        Dim msg As String = "Hello?!"
        Helper.UpdateList(msg) ' <-- You can do this from any class...
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Helper

    Public Shared Sub UpdateList(ByVal itemName As String)
        Dim frm As Form = My.Application.ApplicationContext.MainForm
        If Not IsNothing(frm) Then
            Dim matches() As Control = frm.Controls.Find("ListBox1", True)
            If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is ListBox Then
                Dim LB As ListBox = DirectCast(matches(0), ListBox)
                LB.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() LB.Items.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString & ": " & itemName)))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

Other correct approaches, which would require more work on your part, might include:

(1) Pass a reference to your main form into the other classes as you create them.  Then those classes can either up the ListBox directly, or possibly call a method in it as suggested by Plutonix.  Here's an example of this in action:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub UpdateList(ByVal itemName As String)
        ListBox1.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString & ": " & itemName)))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim soc As New SomeOtherClass(Me)
        soc.Foo()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class SomeOtherClass

    Private _Main As Form1

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal MainForm As Form1)
        _Main = MainForm
    End Sub

    Public Sub Foo()
        If Not IsNothing(_Main) Then
            _Main.UpdateList("Hello?!")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

You'd have to modify all of your other classes in a similar fashion so that they can receive an instance of your form.

(2) Make the other classes raise a custom event that the main form subscribes to when those classes are created.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I should have said that I had used the above but am happy with other approaches as well. Because I am new to this I picked what I thought would work (but may not be the right approach). Thanks for the tips it is appreciated!

Comment: I am sure it is just something I am doing wrong, but with the above example if I put it in a public sub or a shared sub and call it from other classes it does not update the listbox. Should I be creating a sub in each class like the above example?

Comment: Is the form in question the "Startup object" in Project --> Properties?

Comment: ..and no, it shouldn't need to be in every class.  You could make it a Shared sub in a helper class (or the form itself) and it would still work.

Comment: Yep, the form is the startup object, I have added the code I used in the main question, but calling frm.UpdateList("Stuff goes here") does nothing unless it is called within the frm class (and I want to call it from other classes). Thanks!

Comment: So I have done so debug, and It is still not working, I can see that the helper sub is being called from all classes. The issue is that when it is called within the main class (e.g. the frm) it returns matches = 1, but when it is called outside of the main frm the matches.length is not being called (I would think because the if Not IsNothing(frm) part, am I missing something in this case, other than it is almost like it is not finding the form outside of the main class?

Comment: In my example, I'm clearly using the Helper from outside the Form class inside the SomeOtherClass class.  Can you give more details about these other classes that you have?  How are they being created?  What do they do?  I'd need more details to figure out what the difference is...

Comment: Sorry if I have not explained it well, so I have the HelperClass which is in the same file as the form class (form1.vb) and the form class is frm. The frm form itself is the startup form. I then have a number of different classes that handle different things throughout the project, for example I have a "mysql_functions" class which handles writing various things to databases and retrieving different values, I have a server class which handles the websocket server and so on, in the classes I am trying to call Helper.UpdateList("Data Here") to update the list with status messages but no luck.

Comment: Are the other classes still part of the same **Project**?

Comment: Yep, the classes are still part of the same project, and I can call them within different sections, for example if I want to send a message to users from the form class, I can call websocket_helpers.SendMessage("data") and it works fine.

Comment: Note sure what's going on there.  I updated the alternate approach #1 to show how that could be implemented.  Try that out...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think i might have to go back to the drawing board on my approach. I have so many Public Shared Sub's that when I try any approach that is not something along the lines of class.callsub("Info") I get cannot refer to instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member issue. I can't change the public shared either as these are used throughout the classes. I would say the first example is the best but my code is so fragmented and poorly written that trying to achieve what I want does not seem possible. A big thanks for the help though!